# Environment Variable or saving dev_key file

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am slightly new to ubuntu,

I have a NASA-ADS dev_key to access some data on there system but am unable to:

1. save it as an environment variable named `ADS_DEV_KEY` or
2. save it to a file called `~/.ads/dev_key`

after following the instructions in link  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ads/0.0.809

For the first option: I don't know any thing about how to save **an environment variable naming ADS_DEV_KEY**

For 2nd option I am unable to locate any directory naming **.ads** where I should save the text file for available key.

**Note:**

When I import installed ads library to python it gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import ads
    File "/home/sibte/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ads/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
import network
    File "/home/sibte/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ads/network.py", line 15, in <module>
from core import search
    File "/home/sibte/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ads/core.py", line 19, in <module>
DEV_KEY = utils.get_dev_key()
    File "/home/sibte/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ads/utils.py", line 31, in get_dev_key
raise IOError("no ADS API key found in ~/.ads/dev_key and no ADS_DEV_KEY "\
    IOError: no ADS API key found in ~/.ads/dev_key and no ADS_DEV_KEY environment variable found
```

Any help (preferably simple) regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `~/.ads` directory. Assuming the API key is 123, open a terminal window with **Ctrl+Alt+T** and run these commands:

```
mkdir ~/.ads
echo '123' > ~/.ads/dev_key
```

If you want to set an environment variable instead, you can study [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: I used both the tricks but still the same error occured, I create .ads folder in the directory which python mentioned in error i.e; **home/sibte/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ads**
saved the dev_key in the file naming dev_key

Comment: @user3269913: No, the directory should be `/home/sibte/.ads`